# Cannot read property 'FloatingActionButton' in NativeScript using the plugin nativescript-floatingactionbutton

Tags: javascript, android, xml, nativescript

I am fairly new to NativeScript and I need to display a FAB (I am not working with angular). I started from a blank project and installed the plugin from https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton . And then added the xml part for the button in my code. However by just adding this just one line:

```
<FAB:fab class="fab-button" icon="res://ic_add_white" tap="{{ onTap }}" rippleColor="#f1f1f1"/>
```

I have the following error:

An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.MyApp2/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreateView failed

TypeError: Cannot read property 'FloatingActionButton' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.MyApp2/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-floatingactionbutton/fab.js, line: 20, column: 57

Also I ensured that the icon image is in the correct folder.
Here is the main code of the app (it is basically a Helloworld program)

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:FAB="nativescript-floatingactionbutton" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page">
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="My Apps" icon="res://icon" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>
<StackLayout class="p-20">
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"/>
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    <FAB:fab class="fab-button" icon="res://ic_add_white" tap="{{ onTap }}" rippleColor="#f1f1f1"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**main-view-model.js**

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function getMessage(counter) {
    if (counter <= 0) {
       return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
    } else {
       return counter + " taps left";
   }
}

function createViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.counter = 42;
    viewModel.message = getMessage(viewModel.counter);
    viewModel.test = "foo";

    viewModel.onTap = function() {
        this.counter--;
        this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));
    }

    return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

**main-page.js**

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

Also I am using the 3.4.3 version of NativeScript. Thanks in advance for the precious help

Comment: Try resetting your project by removing the platform folder and rebuild the project again (`tns platform remove android`  & `tns run android`) I have created sample project using the FAB button and it works as expected on my side: https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018/tree/master/floatingButton.

Comment: I tried (tns platform remove android & tns run android) but did not resolve the problem then I went to your github repo and tried your code for floating button and it worked. I will try to build my other code from your template. Thank you very much :D
Solved